# How to Show the option select in dropdownlist before the data

Tags: c#, webforms

this is the way I fill it DropDownList, I need the first option to be select and then the data in the database.

```
droplistTipoVisado.DataTextField = "TipoVisado";
droplistTipoVisado.DataValueField = "Id";
droplistTipoVisado.DataSource = _servicio2.TraerTodo();
droplistTipoVisado.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution. Mine is setup different than yours, so it is not tested, but it should still work.

```
droplistTipoVisado.Items.Insert(0, "Select...");//add default select
```

This should be put after the databind.